# PHP Early Binding - Is there an alternative to requiring the file?

Tags: php, class, autoload, early-binding

Premble: I am using composer and autoloader with PHP 8.

I have this class:

```
<?php

namespace Something\Cool;

class Test
{

}

interface TestStorage
{

}

class TestStoragePDOMySQL implements TestStorage
{

}
```

I need to use it as follows:

```
$storage = new TestStoragePDOMySQL();
$system = new Test();
```

This gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Something\Cool\TestStoragePDOMySQL" not found
```

After spending hours doing research the problem seems to be in the way PHP handles early binding as described [here](https://www.npopov.com/2021/10/20/Early-binding-in-PHP.html) and not in the class that can't be found.

I managed to solve the issue in a way I don't like which is requiring the file instead of relying on autoloader:

```
require 'src/Something/Cool.php';
$storage = new TestStoragePDOMySQL();
$bucket = new Test();
```

There must be another way to use autoload instead of this solution but I can't find one. Any help?

Comment: Have you autoloaded the namespace in your composer.json?

Comment: Yes. Given the above example, my `composer.json` has `Something` namespace inside `autoload` -> `psr-4` node pointing to the right directory

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Sure: https://ibb.co/x3v2NHm

Comment: Ok, have you done `composer dump-autoload` after this?